# Error while adding navigation properties C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have these classes

```
public abstract class Entity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Entity()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
}

public class Account : Entity
    {
        public Account() { }

        public Account(string name, Integration integration, User creator, List<User> usersAccessRights)
        {
            Name = name;
            IsActive = integration.HasSuccessfullyConnected;
            CreatedAt = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
            Integration = integration;
            //CreatedBy = creator.Id;
            Creator = creator;
            Users.AddRange(usersAccessRights);
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public long CreatedAt { get; protected set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; protected set; }

        public Guid CreatedBy { get; protected set; }
        public virtual User Creator { get; set; }

        public Guid IntegrationId { get; private set; }
        public virtual Integration Integration { get; private set; }

        public virtual List<User> Users { get; private set; } = new List<User>();
    }

public class User : Entity
    {
        public User() { }
        public User(string name, string email, string phone, string password)
        {
            Name = name;
            Email = email;
            Phone = phone;
            Password = password;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Email { get; private set; }
        public string Phone { get; private set; }
        public string Password { get; private set; }

        public virtual List<Account> Accounts { get; set; } = new List<Account>();

    }

public class Integration : Entity
    {
        public Integration() { }
        protected Integration(string name, bool hasSuccessfullyConnected)
        {
            Name = name;
            IsActive = HasSuccessfullyConnected = hasSuccessfullyConnected;
            CreatedAt = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        }

        public string Name { get; protected set; }
        public long CreatedAt { get; protected set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; protected set; }
        public bool HasSuccessfullyConnected { get; protected set; }
        public string Type { get; protected set; }

        public virtual string IntegrationType() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }



// Repository Add method
private TEntity AddEntity(TEntity entity)
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

// method to get user info
 public virtual TEntity GetById(Guid id)
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
          
        }
```

On creating account request i received the userId (creator) and the informations to create integration and account. First I search for the user creator and then i create the integration. After those steps, i call the account constructor and pass the objects

```
var account = CreateAccount(createAccountRequest.Name, integration, user, usersWithAccess);
var createAccountResult = _accountRepository.Create(account);
```

But I got the error:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_User'. Cannot
> insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.User'. The duplicate key value is
> (3c8a0035-4bc0-4001-bfa9-498d182a7f36).
>  The statement has been
> terminated.

According to the error seems that i tried to create a new user, by i'm just setting the user that create Account

I've tried differents approachs and i've got the same error. I found others examples like this, and they work well, but mine dont

## EDITED:

With this configurations works well

```
var createAccountResult = _accountRepository.Create(account);
_accountRepository.Commit();
account.Creator = creatorResult.Entity;
account.Users.AddRange(usersAccessRights);
_accountRepository.Commit();
```

Comment: EF has no "Entity" or "Repository" classes (which actually looks like a CRUD class). It doesn't need them. It's not possible to guess what's going on in the missing code. If `Create` calls `SaveChanges` though, it's fundamentally broken and breaks EF itself. A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit-of-Work. It detects all changes to the in-memory object it tracks and persists *all* of them when `SaveChanges` is called. That means that `Create` can easily perform 42 UPDATEs, 67 DELETEs and 3 INSERTs. That's a fundamental bug of the entire CRUD-over-EF antipattern

Comment: Without the missing code, one can only guess. My guess is that a row matching the `User` object already exists but `Create` attached it as `Added` it by calling `DbContext.Add(account)`. That's a bug of CRUD classes too. DbContext.Add will attach the object *and* any related ones in the `Added` state. If `User` was loaded by EF itself, the DbContext would know this was already tracked and not change its status. If it was loaded with `AsNoTracking()` though, EF would know nothing about it

Comment: `DbContext.Update` on the other hand is the equivalent of InsertOrUpdate. Again the entire object graph will be attached. Any objects with default PK values will be `Added` while any with non-default keys will be `Modified`. It's more common to use `Update` instead of `Added` unless we really know that an object is completely new

Comment: Please post your code. I made a guess based on the several dozens of questions caused by CRUD classes like this, but it's still just a guess.

Comment: Another big bug is `CreatedAt = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();`. All databases have native *binary* date types. Storing an integer with some assumed meaning *guarantees* errors, breaks cross-platform compatibilty, and makes it impossible to perform date-related queries, indexing or use date functions. There's absolutely no reason to do this. PS: In this case it also eliminates the timezone offset. If your database has a `datetimeoffset` or `datetime with offset` or a similar type, just use `DateTimeOffset`

Comment: I think you were on the right track using the Guid ID to set the associated user - rather than setting the full object - CreateBy = creator.Id - this will avoid EF trying to "add" the entity again in your repo. Having said that I think you could be receiving this error for both the Creator and the Users list so I'd start by making Users an empty list, fix the problem with creator, and then fix it for Users